# JavaScript/jQuery only gets executed on first visit, cookie prevents it from executing again

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make JavaScript (or jQuery) code only execute on the visitor's first visit and never again until a cookie expires or is removed?

For example: `$('#example').hide();` How can I prevent this code from executing for 7 days for this visitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this tut: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/
set a cookie on first visit, read it out on any subsequent visit and do something like:

```
if($.cookie.isset() == true) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do like this. you should use server scripting for additional help.

Eg. in PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['session_name'])){
     ?>
          Your javascript or jquery code here
     <?

    }

?>
```